# Vue: Distinct method in foreach component

Tags: vue.js, foreach, vue-component

I have a child component in foreach loop. The component has two methods what I initiate with a button on the component.

How can I make these methods unique/ every foreach iteration? Becouse if I don't make them distinct even if I push the last iteration's button the first iteration's method will start.

I tried with `methodName+index: function()`, but I got `, expected` error.

**Update**

My parent component:

```
            <div v-for="(card, index) in cards" v-bind:key="index">
                <CardSubComponent 
                    :card="card"
                    @cardSaveSuccess="cardSuccess"
                    @cardSaveError="cardError"
                ></CardSubComponent>
            </div>
```

My subcomponent:

```
<template>
    <div class="box">
        <b-select :id="cardSequenceID" v-model="card.sequence" @input="changeSequence">
            <option
                v-for="sequence in sequenceArray"
                :value="sequence"
                :key="sequence">
                {{ sequence }}
            </option>
        </b-select>
    </div>
</template>
<script>


    export default {
        props:['card'],
        data(){
            return {
                cardSequenceID = 'sequence'+card.id
                sequenceArray: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeSequence(rule){
                axios.post('/api/card/changeSequence', {
                    cardID: card.id,
                    weight: document.getElementById('sequence'+cardID).value
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                    }
                }).then(response => {
                    if(response.data == 'success'){
                        this.$emit('cardSaveSuccess')
                    } else {
                        this.$emit('cardSaveError')
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking but my first instinct is that instead of having multiple functions with distinct names you should have one function and pass it different arguments. If you could post some code it would help clarify. For starters, it isn't really clear what a 'component in a foreach loop' means in a Vue context.

Comment: I have a component what's in a div what's in a foreach loop and for every iteration I parse that component.

Comment: Do you mean `v-for`? Please edit the question to include enough code for us to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added some code snippets. I want to change the sequence of the cards but if I change the 3rd cards `select` the first card's method runs

Comment: Just pass the card object or its id as an argument so that you can check which card called the method, no?

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add arguments to your method calls. Something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <CardSubComponent
      v-for="(card, index) in cards"
      :key="index"
      :card="card"
      @cardSaveError="cardError(card)"
      @cardSaveSuccess="cardSuccess(card)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    cardError(card) {
      // TODO: Add error handler here
      console.log('error called with:', card.id);
    },
    cardSuccess(card) {
      // TODO: Add success handler here
      console.log('success called with:', card.id);
    },
  },
};
```

In the child component there are two things wrong:

1. `cardSequenceID` was not properly initialized (you were using `=` instead of `:`)
2. You were missing `this` in `this.card.id` to identify the id for your `axios` call

```js
export default {
  props: ['card'],
  data() {
    return {
      sequenceArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      cardSequenceID: `sequence${card.id}`,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeSequence(rule) {
      axios
        .post(
          '/api/card/changeSequence',
          {
            cardID: this.card.id,
            weight: document.getElementById(`sequence${cardID}`).value,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            },
          }
        )
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data === 'success') {
            this.$emit('cardSaveSuccess');
          } else {
            this.$emit('cardSaveError');
          }
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but the `changeSequence` method runs in wrong place.

Comment: Can you say more about what that means? Note the `cardSuccess(card)` in the template - you'd need to make that change and the change to the method for this to work.

Comment: I change the select in the 3rd card. What I expect: the 3rd card `changeSequence` method fires and sends that card's new sequence place to the backend. What happens: The 1st card `changeSequence` triggers

Comment: See the updated solution. Two other thoughts: (1) please install a linter - eslint would have caught this, (2) `getElementById` is a hack. You should be able to derive this based on the rule or other data.